# Comparing two arrays with angular8

Tags: angular

I have two arrays list and I need to ceck the values of two arrays.

This is working correctly but how can I add the else condition ?

```
<li *ngFor="let product of categories; let num = index">
          <div *ngIf="product.id === model.categoriesListDTO[num].id">
            {{product.id}}
          </div>
</li>
```

Answer (score 0):

try “else” statement of Angular

```
<li *ngFor="let product of categories; let num = index">
 <div *ngIf="product.id === model.categoriesListDTO[num].id; else notEqual">
        {{product.id}}
 </div>
 <ng-template #notEqual>
  not equal content
 </ng-template> 
</li>
```

Answer (score 0):

Good day! You can use `else` keyword in `ngIf` directive with ref to the ng-template directive.

```
<li *ngFor="let product of categories; let num = index">
  <div *ngIf="product.id === model.categoriesListDTO[num].id; else tpl">
    {{ product.id }}
  </div>
  <ng-template #tpl>
    Any content for else condition goes here..
  </ng-template>
</li>
```